# I want to implement a message inbox in nodejs using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-developer-toolbar

I am trying to implement a messaging feature for users on my website. So that they can send messages to each other. My website is based on NODEJS, EXPRESS, MongoDB. Any hint or reference will be a great help in this direction.

Comment: please take the question to the point of code or errors and then post here for help.